# Python difference in script

Tags: python

What is the difference between these 2 script that giving different results. I could not realize any difference.

**#script 1 results i get:**

*True
False
True*

**#script 2 results i get:**

*False
False
True*

**Scritp #1:**

```
def is_palindrome(input_string):
    # We'll create two strings, to compare them
    new_string = ""
    reverse_string = ""
    input_string =input_string.lower()
    # Traverse through each letter of the input string
    for x in input_string:
        # Add any non-blank letters to the 
        # end of one string, and to the front
        # of the other string.

        if x!=" ":
            new_string =new_string+ x
            reverse_string = x+reverse_string
    # Compare the strings
    if new_string==reverse_string:
        return True
    return False
    
print(is_palindrome("Never Odd or Even")) # Should be True
print(is_palindrome("abc")) # Should be False
print(is_palindrome("kayak")) # Should be True
```

**Script#2:**

```
def is_palindrome(input_string):
    # We'll create two strings, to compare them
    new_string = ""
    reverse_string = ""
    input_string =input_string.lower()
    # Traverse through each letter of the input string
    for x in input_string:
        # Add any non-blank letters to the 
        # end of one string, and to the front
        # of the other string.
        if x!="":
            new_string =new_string+x
            reverse_string = x+reverse_string
    # Compare the strings
    if new_string==reverse_string:
        return True
    return False

print(is_palindrome("Never Odd or Even")) # Should be True
print(is_palindrome("abc")) # Should be False
print(is_palindrome("kayak")) # Should be True
```

Comment: The only difference is `if x!="":`. Do you see now why it leads to different results?

Comment: the only difference is the spaces below "of the other string" and in the if statment. It must be something else in the script, this text isn't the problem

Comment: The second script will add the spaces as well

Answer (score 0):

Difference is:

```
if x!=" ":
```

versus

```
if x!="":
```

First result in ignoring spaces, second does not ignore anything - consider following example:

```
text = "H ELLO"
for x in text:
    if x!=" ":
        print(x)
```

Output:

```
H
E
L
L
O
```

whilst

```
text = "H ELLO"
for x in text:
    if x!="":
        print(x)
```

output

```
H

E
L
L
O
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference is the argument of the if : in the second code you have

```
 if x != ''
```

which isn't the condition you want ; what you want is

```
if x != ' '
```